# How to import protocol buffer definitions from another Python package?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have my directory structure like this:

```
root/
  sift/
    __init__.py
    sift_descriptors.proto
    sift_descriptors_pb2.py
  project/
    __init__.py
    filtered_descriptors.proto
    filtered_descriptors_pb2.py
    filtered_descriptors_test.py
```

The root directory is in my `$PYTHONPATH`.

I build `root/sift/sift_descriptors_pb2.py` using `protoc --python_out=./ sift_descriptors.proto`

I build `root/project/filtered_descriptors_pb2.py` using `/cs/public/lib/pkg/protobuf/bin/protoc --proto_path=../sift --proto_path=./ --python_out=./ filtered_descriptors.proto`

In `filtered_descriptors.proto`, I use `import "sift_descriptors.proto"`

The problem is that in `filtered_descriptors_pb2.py` (produced by protoc), there's a statement that just does this bare import: `import sift_descriptors_pb2`, without reference via the module name as would be needed: `from sift import sift_descriptors_pb2`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it!

The solution was to use `import "sift/sift_descriptors.proto"` in `filtered_descriptors.proto`, and then point `protoc` to `--proto_path=../` instead of `--proto_path=../sift`.

Then, protoc generates python code that does the import as `import sift.sift_descriptors_pb2`.

Comment: Talking with the maintainers of protocol buffers, --proto_path is supposed to point to the root of the package hierarchy and all imports should be fully qualified. Not well described in the documentation, but they'll fix it up :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't add .py to the import statement:  "from sift import sift_descriptors_pb2"

Comment: Thanks! But, just to be clear, my question still stands. I had just asked it incorrectly at first.